# gnu parallel for macs peak calling

Tags: shell, macs2

These are the list of files

```
Control_Input_sorted.bam_rem.bam  
Control_H2BUb_sorted.bam_rem.bam  
Control_IgG_sorted.bam_rem.bam 
PTPN6_g2_6_H2Bub_sorted.bam_rem.bam  
PTPN6_g2_6_Input_sorted.bam_rem.bam
```

So to get unique files i do this

```
 ls -1 *bam | sort | sed -r 's/_sorted.bam_rem.bam//g' | sort | uniq 
Control_Input
Control_H2BUb
Control_IgG
PTPN6_g2_6_H2Bub
PTPN6_g2_6_Input
```

Now i have to run each sample against input and IgG for peak-calling.
Like  `Control_H2BUb_sorted.bam_rem.bam` against

```
Contol_Input_sorted.bam_rem.bam & Control_IgG_sorted.bam_rem.bam and 


PTPN6_g2_6_H2Bub_sorted.bam_rem.bam against PTPN6_g2_6_Input_sorted.bam_rem.bam
```

So how do I parse and execute using gnu parallel.

I came across this [tutorial](http://crazyhottommy.blogspot.com/2015/09/macs2-parallel-peak-calling.html) where it does something like this

```
cat sample_names.txt | parallel --max-procs=12 'macs2 callpeak -t {}-A-NC.sorted.bam \
 -c {}-G-NC.sorted.bam -g hs -n {}-A-NC-sharp-model -q 0.01 --outdir {}-A-NC-sharp-model-peaks 2> {}-A-NC-sharp-model.stderr'
```

Now im not sure how to pass the file names as argument for IP and Input or IgG.

If i use logic a little bit i have to fix Control and PTPN6_g2_6 as constant naming!.

Any suggestion or help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not gnuparallel but **nextflow**. I don't know macs and what is 'first.bam' and 'second.bam' is not clear not me but I hope you'll get the idea.

The nextflow:

```
Channel.fromPath(params.bams).splitCsv(header: false,sep:'\t',strip:true).map{T->file(T[0])}.into{bams1;bams2}

boolean isControl(file) {
    return file.name.endsWith("_Input_sorted.bam_rem.bam") || file.name.endsWith("_IgG_sorted.bam_rem.bam ");
    }

bams1.filter{T->isControl(T)}.set{controls}
bams2.filter{T->!isControl(T)}.set{experiment}

process mac {
    maxForks 14
    tag "${bam1} vs ${bam2}"
    input:
        set bam1 , bam2  from experiment.combine(controls)
    output:
        file("output.peaks") into mac_peak
    script:
    """
    # check syntax please
    macs2 callpeak -t {bam1.toRealPath()}  -c ${bam2.toRealPath()} -g hs -n out-model -q 0.01 --outdir output.peaks
    """
    }
```

invoke:

```
find /dir1/dir2 -type f -name "*.bam" > input.list

nextflow run --bams input.list workflow.nf
```

Comment: okay let me give it a try first and update you.

Comment: my first try ended up like this "Not a valid project name: workflow.nf" I need to read the basics of nextflow

Comment: first bam is my Control_H2BUb and PTPN6_g2_6_H2Bub , and it should be compared with samples labelled Control_Input,Control_IgG and PTPN6_g2_6_Input which are second bam. But the catch is the Control lablled samples should always be compared with the control labelled and same goes with PTPN6 labelled